# How can you embed an iframe in a twitter status update

Tags: api, iframe, twitter, embed

On [kickstarter.com](http://kickstarter.com), When you publish to twitter about a project , the tweet includes an iframe with the some of Kickstarter project details embedded in the media content, such as here:

https://twitter.com/asfaltboy/status/211421708639416322

To re-create such a tweet, go to [some ks page](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/texmurphy/tex-murphy-project-fedora) and click the "tweet" link under the video. The tweet content seems to be some simple text with a **link to the project page**.

This probably means that the iframe content is referenced in some meta tag of that page.. but I could not for the life of me figure which meta tag it is...

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called *Twitter Cards*. You tweet a link to your page where Twitter spider can find data for the card: `<meta property="twitter:card" content="...`

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards

But according to documentation `Twitter Cards will only render for domains which have been whitelisted by Twitter.` If your site is big enaugh and has quality content, then you might get whitelisted.